# Android: progress dialog error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to adapt two tutorial, to learn Volley.

I have error with showing a progress dialog.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final static String MARS_WEATHER_RECENT = "http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/";
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private TextView debug_container;
    private TextView degrees;

    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        debug_container = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.debug_container);
        degrees = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.degrees);

        loadMarsWeatherData();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    }

    private void loadMarsWeatherData() {

        showpDialog();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                MARS_WEATHER_RECENT, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object
                    response = response.getJSONObject("report");
                    String min_degree = response.getString("min_temp");

                    degrees.setText(min_degree);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }





    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Error is

```
    [...]
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webtemplum.crazyweather/com.webtemplum.crazyweather.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
[...]
used by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.webtemplum.crazyweather.MainActivity.showpDialog(MainActivity.java:222)
            at com.webtemplum.crazyweather.MainActivity.loadMarsWeatherData(MainActivity.java:56)
            at com.webtemplum.crazyweather.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
```

(Stripped out some error line, If I understood right the error is in showpDialog).

Of course, If I comment the `showpDialog` app runs.

Same thing (app runs) if I comment all block in `loadWeatherData` and leave only

```
private void loadMarsWeatherData() {

        showpDialog();
        hidepDialog();
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Something is `null` in `MainActivity.java`, line 222.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this segment of code:

```
loadMarsWeatherData();

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

You're calling `loadMarsWeatherData` before instantiating `pDialog`. However, in `loadMarsWeatherData` you're calling `pDialog`:

```
showpDialog();
```

will call:

```
private void showpDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}
```

You need to change the order - first instantiate pDialog and then call the method:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);

loadMarsWeatherData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `loadMarsWeatherData()` before declaring the Progress Dialog which returns a null. Just put the `loadMarsWeatherData()` after declairing the Progress Dialog.

```
 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
 pDialog.setCancelable(false);

 loadMarsWeatherData();
```

And you are all done!